# How can I run a set method over lists in terms of dictionary keys / values to find unique items and list the comparison results?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, key-value-store

I have a dictionary with values as lists of text values. (ID : [text values])
Below is an excerpt.

```
data_dictionary = {
    52384: ['text2015', 'webnet'], 
    18720: ['datascience', 'bigdata', 'links'],
    82465: ['biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining', 'datamodel', 'semantics'],
    73120: ['links', 'scientometrics'],
    22276: ['text2015', 'webnet'],
    97376: ['text2015', 'webnet'],
    43424: ['biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining', 'datamodel', 'semantics'],
    23297: ['links', 'scientometrics'],
    45233: ['webnet', 'conference', 'links']
}
```

I created a default dictionary to show the text values that are unique and their lists of unique keys.

```
dd = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dictionary_name.items():
        dd[tuple(v)].append(k)
```

Which gave the resulting list of unique IDs and their text values:

`{('text2015', 'webnet'): [52384, 22276, 97376], ('datascience', 'bigdata', 'links'): [18720], ('biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining', 'datamodel', 'semantics'): [82465, 43424], ('links', 'scientometrics'): [73120, 23297]}`)

Each of these keys has a sum which I extract from the sum_dictionary.

```
def extract_sum(key_id, sum_dictionary):
    for k,v in sum_dictionary.items():
        if key_id == k:
            k_sum = v
    return k_sum
```

The extracted sum dictionary can be found here.

```
sum_dict = { 52384:1444856137000,18720:1444859841000, 82465:1444856, 22276:1674856137000,  97376:1812856137000,43424:5183856,23297:1614481000, 45233:1276781300}
```

I want to output files that have one or more similar text values including if one value has more or less of the shared text values. And to get a result that is in the form of:

> ID_1 ; ID_2 ; Sum_for_ID_1 ; Sum_for_ID_2 ; [one or more shared text values between ID_1 and ID_2]

where Sum_for_ID_1 < Sum_for_ID_2

> 45233 ; 52384 ; 1276781300 ; 1444856137000 ; ['webnet']
>
> 52384 ; 97376 ; 1444856137000 ; 1812856137000 ; ['text2015', 'webnet']
>
> 18720 ; 18720 ; 1444859841000 ; 1444859841000 ; ['datascience','bigdata', 'links']
>
> 73120 ; 23297 ; 144481000 ; 1614481000 ; ['links', 'scientometrics']

(per line)

I tried using itertools to find all combinations of all the words in the dictionary values but the iterations take too much time to work out.

I thought about running a set method over the keys as well to find similar values. Any ideas would really help.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output, since it's hard to follow what is the process.

Comment: The edit has been made to include the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the full solution to your problem, but part of it, as i believe it solves most of the problem:

```
In [1]: data_dictionary = {
   ...:     52384: ['text2015', 'webnet'],
   ...:     18720: ['datascience', 'bigdata', 'links'],
   ...:     82465: ['biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining', 'datamodel', 'semantics'],
   ...:     73120: ['links', 'scientometrics'],
   ...:     22276: ['text2015', 'webnet'],
   ...:     97376: ['text2015', 'webnet'],
   ...:     43424: ['biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining', 'datamodel', 'semantics'],
   ...:     23297: ['links', 'scientometrics'],
   ...:     45233: ['webnet', 'conference', 'links']
   ...: }

In [2]: from itertools import combinations
   ...:
   ...: intersections = []
   ...:
   ...: for first, second in combinations(data_dictionary.items(), r=2):
   ...:     intersection = set(first[1]) & set(second[1])
   ...:     if intersection:
   ...:         intersections.append((first[0], second[0], list(intersection)))
   ...:

In [3]: intersections
Out[3]:
[(52384, 22276, ['webnet', 'text2015']),
 (52384, 97376, ['webnet', 'text2015']),
 (52384, 45233, ['webnet']),
 (18720, 73120, ['links']),
 (18720, 23297, ['links']),
 (18720, 45233, ['links']),
 (82465,
  43424,
  ['semantics', 'datamodel', 'biological', 'biomedics', 'datamining']),
 (73120, 23297, ['links', 'scientometrics']),
 (73120, 45233, ['links']),
 (22276, 97376, ['webnet', 'text2015']),
 (22276, 45233, ['webnet']),
 (97376, 45233, ['webnet']),
 (23297, 45233, ['links'])]
```

What it does, it creates pairs of every element of your `data_dictionary` and then checks if intersections of values is not empty, then it puts that in `intersections` array in form of `(key1, key2, intersection)`.

I hope that i gave you a quick-start from which you can finish your task.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answered example [from vishes_shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857943/5550563) above, I managed to get most of the desired output. In order to add individual sums, I considered having to rerun the extract sum method which seems non-optimal. So I left it out of the solution as I think up a different path.

```
for first, second in combinations(data_dictionary.items(), r=2):
    intersection = set(first[1]) & set(second[1])
    if intersection:
        sum1 = extract_sum(first[0], sum_dict)
        sum2 = extract_sum(second[0], sum_dict)
        if sum1 < sum2:
            early =first[0]
            late = second[0]
        else:
            early = second[0]
            late = first[0]

        filename.write('%d , %d , %s' % (early, late, list(intersection)))
        filename.write('\n')
```